# Vector space and its dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, and $U,W \subseteq V$ subspaces of $V$.

We define :

$$
\begin{align}
W^\circ &= \big\{ φ \in V^* \mid \forall w \in W : φ(w) = 0 \big\} & \subseteq V^* \\
U^\circ &= \big\{ φ \in V^* \mid \forall u \in U : φ(u) = 0 \big\} & \subseteq V^*
\end{align}
$$

Prove that if $\dim(V) < \infty$, then $(U∩W)^\circ = U^\circ + W^\circ$.

How do I get into this proof?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HenryW. then there's no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ U^o+W^o\subset (U\cap W)^o$.  To see this, remark that $f\in U^o$ implies that $f(x)=0, x\in U$, in particular, $f(x)=0, x\in U\cap W$, thus $U^o\subset (U\cap W)^o$, also $W^o\subset (U\cap W)^o$, thus $U^o+W^o\subset (U\cap W)^o$.

$dim (U^o)= dim(V)-dim(U)$.

$dim(U^o+W^o)=dim(U^o)+dim(W^o)-dim(U^o\cap W^o)=2dim(V)-dim(U)-dim(W)-dim(U^o\cap V^o)$.

Remark that $U^o\cap W^o =(U+W)^o$ so $dim(U^o\cap W^o) =dim(V)-dim(U+W)=dim(V)-dim(U)-dim(W)+dim(U\cap W)$,

thus $dim(U^o+W^o)=2dim(V)-dim(U)-dim(W)-dim(V)+dim(U)+dim(W)-dim(U\cap W)=n-dim(U\cap W)= dim(U\cap W)^o$.

Comment: that just tells you that the dimensions are the same

Comment: But $U^o+W^o\subset (U\cap W)^o$ if they have the same dimension they are equal.

Comment: Well there you go, then.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove $(U∩W)° \subset (U° + W°)$ *and* $(U∩W)° \supset (U° + W°)$.

For the first direction: suppose that $\varphi \in (U \cap W)^\circ$.  That is, for any $v \in U \cap W$, we have $\varphi(v) = 0$.  We know that $U \cap W$ needs to be a subspace of both $U$ and $W$.  So, we can find subspaces $A \subset U$ and $B \subset W$ such that
$$
V = A \oplus B \oplus (U \cap W)
$$
We may therefore define (unique) maps $\varphi_U$ and $\varphi_W$ such that
$$
\varphi_U(v) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & v \in U \cap W\\
0 & v \in A\\
\varphi(v) & v \in B
\end{cases} \qquad
\varphi_W(v) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & v \in U \cap W\\
\varphi(v) & v \in A\\
0 & v \in B
\end{cases}
$$
We then have $\varphi = \varphi_U + \varphi_W$ where $\varphi_U \in U^\circ$ and $\varphi_W \in W^\circ$.

Perhaps now you can try to get the other direction.